# Remembering to run tests before commit

Tags: python, unit-testing, build-automation, teamcity

We have a decent set of unit tests on our code and those unit tests run in under 2 minutes. We also use TeamCity to do a build and to run tests after each check in.  However, we still get issues where a developer "forgets" to run all the tests before a commit resulting in TeamCity failure which if this check in was done at 6PM may stay broken over night.

"Forgets" is a generic term, there a couple other common reasons why even remembering to run the tests could result in TeamCity failure. Such as.

-> A developer only checks in some of the modified files in his/her workspace.
-> A file was modified outside of eclipse such that eclipse's team synchronize perspective does not detect it as dirty.

How do you deal with this in your organization?

We are thinking of introducing "check in procedure" for developers which will be an automated tool that will automatically run all unit tests and then commit all of the "dirty" files in your workspace.  Have you had any experience with such process?  Are you aware of any tools which may facilitate this process?   Our dev environment is Python using Eclipse's PyDev plugin.

Comment: This may or may not help, I've only used it for Visual Studio and a msbuild script that includes unit tests.  There is a eclipse add in that does a build (with unit tests if necessary) before check in. It looks like there is a similar thing for eclipse. http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/supported_platforms.html#Supported_IDEs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For mercurial you can use hooks, that will run tests and only allow push on success. But this may require a lot of time for a push (but developer has to run those tests anyway).

Or you can just have own set of bash scripts, that will run test and only then run commit command. For example for django and svn commit it could look as simple as this:

```
./manage.py test && svn commit $@
```

Or there is another way: if anyone commits code, that doesn't pass test, he pays some sum. Soon people will remember to test, for they won't like the notion of paying money ;-)

Comment: i do an alias                                                                alias svnci="bundle exec rspec spec && svn ci -m "

Answer (score 7):

In one of the teams I was working before we had an agreement that anyone who breaks the tests buys bacon sandwiches for the whole team the next morning. Its extreme, but it works perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

I think it is more of a social problem rather than a deficiency of the automated systems.

Yes, you can improve the systems in place, but they will be no match for someone thinking of the implications of their commit, and testing it before they hit commit.

Comment: I agree with this, and a lot could be done with training.  We've also been trying to use various feedback mechanisms and have gotten a lot better at it. But there is still a failure at least once a week.  

So I wonder if asking everyone to consistently perform a multi step check in process is too much to ask and we should just have a tool for that.

Comment: +1.  Odd that I read this as I stared at a broken main for the past 24 hours due to someone committing and leaving.  My group had been pretty good about the "commit and ensure" process, but it has started to slip recently.  Another, larger, group we work with gives folks 1 hour to fix their build issue, or the changes are reverted.  When doing training and discussing with your team, they need to be onboard with committing to the common tree of development means you commit and ensure the changes are valid.  Otherwise, you are impeding the ability of your teammates to do their job.

Answer (score 3):

TeamCity has some support for [pretested commit](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/delayed_commit.html); if your development team is using a supported IDE, you might look into that.

In my company, we don't worry about it too much - our pattern looks something like this.

(a) each developer has their own project configuration in TeamCity, with roots pointing to their own sandbox.  They are allowed to do anything they like here.

(b) the development team has an integration sandbox, where all changes are delivered.  A project encapsulates the configurations which monitor this branch in the source control system.  Dev Leads get to make up the rules here, but that rule is almost always "it must stay green".  I'd have to look at the exact percentage of clean builds - it's not a perfect record, but its high enough that I've never been tempted to insist that the developers be more disciplined about running tests.

(c) the actual deliver comes from a Main stream, which Shall Stay Green (tm).  Dev lead is responsible for delivering a clean snapshot of integration to the main stream on a well defined schedule.  This project is the one that actually generates the installers that are delivered to testing, the bits that go into escrow, etc.

One reason that you might get a way with a more aggressive policy than we do is that our build cycle is slow - on the order of four hours.  If we were an order of magnitude smaller, with a poor success rate, I might argue a different case.

Comment: Do you do this with subversion or a DVCS?  If subversion, how do you manage developer sandboxes?

Comment: The policies were formed while we were using Perforce; each sandbox was mapped to a branch.

Answer (score 0):

For git you can:   http://francoisgaudin.com/2011/02/16/run-django-tests-automatically-before-committing-on-git/

> Run Django tests automatically before committing on Git
>
> Since I often forget to run unit tests before committing, I spend a
>   lot of time looking for the bad commit when I find regressions 3
>   commits later.
>
> However it’s really easy to automatically run tests before each
>   commit. In .git/hooks/pre-commit, put :

```
python manage.py 
test exit $?
```

> then chmod 755 this file and it’s done. I really love git :-)
>
> Do not forget to source your virtualenv before committing.
>
> Note that tests are run on your working tree and not the commit
>   itself, so if you commit only a part of your working tree, it may fail
>   while your commit passes tests.